# What is the most performant way for a game engine to poll gamecontrollers?

Tags: c++, input, multithreading, controllers

I am working on a game engine, and currently I hesitate on this decision.
I developed a library that allows Dualsense and Dualshock4 devices to be used in the engine. XBox Support is made possible via Windows.gaming.input.

While XInput offers a simple way to get events via callbacks, it abstracts away what is going on under the hood.

My current idea was to use one thread per found controller and poll it by a 500Hz rate. Events would be stacked on an event queue.
The problem I encountered with that approach is that, when the framerate of the engine drops dramatically down to the <60 FPS, events are processed with heavy delay, up to a few seconds.

The problem here is that I can't simply reduce the polling rate drastically, as I could potentially miss out on button presses etc.
My current thoughts include storing a full "snapshot" of the controller states instead of reacting to events such as stick movement. This way I would have less packets and packets would include multiple information. Especially when stick movement is fast, I would still run into limitations when the framerate is low. The next thought I had is about introducing stick deadzones, which would again reduce the number of events.

Am I on the right track or am I missing something very obvious, or maybe do I even use worst practices?

Comment: What would you *really* lose by just using XInput and its callback-based API?

Comment: Also I don't understand why the framerate dropping below 60 FPS would cause input delays of multiple seconds. When you only have 25 FPS and you process input events between each two render-frames, then you are still able to empty the input event queue every 40ms. There got to be something else that's buggy here.

Comment: @Philipp I can't just flush the whole input queue on a new frame. If there was a button press and button up during that time, only the button up would correctly get trigged, unless I parse every single event. If I were to check in that frame if a button was up AND the same button was down, I surely will run into issues.

Comment: And regarding XInput: 
I intend to support DInput and XInput devices, which forces me to build a common wrapper

Comment: "If I were to check in that frame if a button was up AND the same button was down, I surely will run into issues" Multiple major engines do it this way, and have successfully shipped hundreds of titles, so I'm not sure this needs to be a deal-breaker. The granularity of human input is much coarser than what you seem to be designing for.

Comment: @DMGregory Really ? Do you have any reference regarding that ? I would have thought major game engines specially prevent this from happening.

Comment: One example is the classic input system in Unity, in which GetButtonDown() and GetButtonUp() can both return true in a single frame, indicating that the button was both pressed and released in this frame's time interval. This rarely happens in play at a normal framerate though - it's actually quite difficult to alternate presses and releases that fast - and it's possible to disambiguate whether it was "release then immediately re-press" or "press then immediate release" by just remembering your pressed state from the previous frame.

Comment: @DMGregory That is interesting. I actually used Unity for quite a while but never really noticed this, as I just assumed that it would not be possible.

Comment: @DMGregory Just one more question since it seems like you are pretty well informed. 
Would I spawn one thread per input device for polling, or just use one thread and poll every device ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough experience with the low-level details to leave a proper answer below. With regard to threading, just be aware that there is a cost to switching threads. So unless you expect polling one device to block the thread an unreasonable amount of time (which shouldn't happen with any APIs I know of), I'd err on the side of combining them.

Comment: Measure. Test. Troubleshoot. Why is the framerate low? What work is the computer doing in that time? Where is the delay coming from?